# JQuery Form Submission API AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

Does anybody have any idea why this is not allowing the form to submit? I'm attempting to use Rotten Tomatoes API with a user search function.

**FORM IN PHP PAGE**

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET"><h3>Search for a movie here:</h3><br> 
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="">&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!">
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('form[name="myform"]').submit(function() {
    $('#films table').empty(); //removes previous search results before adding the new ones.

    var apikey = "frceg2d5djxezaedgm3qq94h";
    var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";
    var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/movies.json?apikey=' + apikey;
    var query = form.inputbox.value;  //uses the value from the input box as the query search



      // sends the query
      $.ajax({
        url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: searchCallback // if successful, run searchCallback function
      });


    // receives the results

    function searchCallback(data) {
     $('#films table').append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + query);
     var movies = data.movies;
     $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {
        $('#films table').append('<tr><td width="70" rowspan="2"><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
        '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '."><img class="ajaximage" src="'
        + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" /></a></td><td class="ajaxfilmlisttitle"><h3><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
        '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '.">' + movie.title + '</a></h3>Release year: '
        + movie.year + '</td></tr><tr><td class="ajaxfilmlistinfo">Audience Score: ' + movie.ratings.audience_score +
        '%<br>' + 'Cinema Release Date: ' + movie.release_dates.theater +
        '<br>Runtime: ' + movie.runtime + ' minutes</td></tr>');
    });
     };
    });
```

Comment: It seems as if you don't have this javascript in an document.ready() wrapper.  Is the javascript output before the form itself?

Comment: It worked without a document ready tag previously, but only with the onClick function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with this code and it works:

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
    <h3>Search for a movie here:</h3>
    <input type="text" id="inputbox" value="" />&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>

<script>

    $(function(){

        $('form[name="myform"]').on('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $('#films table').empty(); //removes previous search results before adding the new ones.

            var apikey = "frceg2d5djxezaedgm3qq94h";
            var baseUrl = "http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0";
            var moviesSearchUrl = baseUrl + '/movies.json?apikey=' + apikey;
            var query = $('#inputbox').val(); //uses the value from the input box as the query search

            // sends the query
            $.ajax({
                url: moviesSearchUrl + '&q=' + encodeURI(query),
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: searchCallback // if successful, run searchCallback function
            });

            // receives the results
            function searchCallback(data) {
                $('#films table').append('Found ' + data.total + ' results for ' + query);
                var movies = data.movies;
                $.each(movies, function(index, movie) {
                    $('#films table').append('<tr><td width="70" rowspan="2"><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
                    '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '."><img class="ajaximage" src="'
                    + movie.posters.thumbnail + '" /></a></td><td class="ajaxfilmlisttitle"><h3><a href="' + movie.links.alternate +
                    '" title="Click here to view film information for ' + movie.title + '.">' + movie.title + '</a></h3>Release year: '
                    + movie.year + '</td></tr><tr><td class="ajaxfilmlistinfo">Audience Score: ' + movie.ratings.audience_score +
                    '%<br>' + 'Cinema Release Date: ' + movie.release_dates.theater +
                    '<br>Runtime: ' + movie.runtime + ' minutes</td></tr>');
                });
            };
        });
    });
</script>
```

There were a couple of problems:

- The `form.inputbox.value` did not work, change it to `$('#inputbox').val()`
- Add `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the from from being submitted
- There was a missing `});`
- Change `$('form[name="myform"]').submit(function() {` to `$('form[name="myform"]').on('submit', function(e) {`

Comment: Unfortunately that wasn't the solution. The URL changes to recognise the submit, but it doesnt actually retrieve the API data.

Comment: Maybe try changing the dataType from `jsonp` to `json`?

Comment: I just did a test using your code, and it works. What if you prevent the form from being submitted? `$('form[name="myform"]').submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault();`

Comment: No luck either, I'm really not sure why it wont obtain results.

It worked with a onClick and declaration of function, but that doesnt allow submission with the enter key.

Comment: I updated the answer with code that I tested that works (with notes on what changed)

Comment: I would kiss you if I could :P Thank you so much :)